# git branch crossover error

Tags: ios, git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Looking for a general suggestion as I occasionally run into errors in branches in my iOS git efforts. I create branches from dev to isolate changes as per usual. I start out with everything tracked, including pods. I commit often from Xcode to remote, and only use SourceTree to manage higher level stuff like branches, merges etc.

BUT.. every so often, when i return to a branch and compile before restarting efforts, i see "no such file or directory" errors for a file or three from *other* branches. I just don't see what i am doing wrong, unless staging every file is my mistake.

Is this enough for somebody to offer advice? If not, and if the question is too general, feel free to wipe it, thank you.

Comment: What kinda files go missing? Are they your files or Pods files?

Comment: It is a file added to another branch. That is the part that is confusing me.